# dropping temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, drop-table

I have 3 php scripts: in 1st one I create a temporary table (in MySQL) with name based on User ID, in 2nd I use that table and give a message to the user, in the 3rd one I use and delete temporary table and give message to the user.
My problem is that if user closes browser when he/she is on the 2nd page, I’m left with a temporary table in the database that needs to be dropped. What’s the best way to solve this?

Comment: have a scheduled job that deletes temp databases that haven't been used in a certain period, or when the user logs out?

Comment: Try to get rid of temporary tables

Comment: Is it truly a temporary table or is that your description? IE 'create temporary table foo... '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a common DB handle for all the access you could use 'create temporary table <contents>' and it would be deleted automatically when the handle is closed. This would clean up the mess should the session get closed prematurely.

Answer (score 3):

This is *very* poor practice. Create the table *ONCE* and insert/delete rows based on user actions. Use a timestamp on each row and have a cleanup script run periodically to remove old entries.